# LibGDX Assets dependencies reduce progress

Tags: kotlin, libgdx

It's more of a general question about the framework itself (specifically, *AssetManager*) rather than a question about the code.

I've been working on a custom loader to cache the outline effect for my texture atlases when I noticed that the progress bar in the loading state of my game dropping percentage at some point. It was my loader which required dependencies to be loaded: a base atlas and a shader (and also another atlas for depth texture).

My loader looks generally like this (in Kotlin):

```
class OutlineLoader(
    resolver: FileHandleResolver
) : AsynchronousAssetLoader<OutlineAtlas, OutlineLoader.Parameter>(resolver) {
    override fun loadSync(manager: AssetManager, name: String, 
                          file: FileHandle, params: Parameter): OutlineAtlas {
        val sourceAtlas = assetManager.get<TextureAtlas>(name)
        val depthAtlas = assetManager.get<TextureAtlas>(params.depth)
        val shader = assetManager.get<ShaderProgram>(params.shader)

        return OutlineAtlas(sourceAtlas, depthAtlas, shader)
    }

    override fun getDependencies(name: String, file: FileHandle, 
                                 params: Parameter) =
            Array<AssetDescriptor<*>>().also { array ->
                listOf(
                        AssetDescriptor(name, TextureAtlas::class.java),
                        AssetDescriptor(params.depth, TextureAtlas::class.java),
                        AssetDescriptor(params.shader, ShaderProgram::class.java)
                ).forEach(array::add)
            }


    ...
}
```

So, I'm queueing some assets and later use them. AssetManager's Logger output confirm it. Yet the progress goes to 25%, then to 20%; to 60%, then to 33%. I inserted debug-print statement to watch loading progress after every `assetManager.update()` call, and it's something like this:

```
[AssetManager] Queued: sprites/sprites.atlas, foo.bar.OutlineAtlas
[AssetManager] Loading: sprites/sprites.atlas, foo.bar.OutlineAtlas
[DEBUG] Loading: 0%
[AssetManager] Loading dependency: sprites/sprites.atlas, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas
[AssetManager] Loading dependency: sprites/depth.atlas, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas
[AssetManager] Loading dependency: shader/depth.frag, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram
[DEBUG] Loading: 0%
[AssetManager] Loaded: 20.16505ms shader/depth.frag, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram
[DEBUG] Loading: 25%
[AssetManager] Loading dependency: sprites/depth.png, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
[DEBUG] Loading: 20%
[AssetManager] Loaded: 20.56412ms sprites/depth.png, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
[DEBUG] Loading: 40%
[AssetManager] Loaded: 85.70349ms sprites/depth.atlas, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas
[DEBUG] Loading: 60%
[AssetManager] Loading dependency: sprites/sprites.png, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
[AssetManager] Loading dependency: sprites/sprites2.png, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
[AssetManager] Loading dependency: sprites/sprites3.png, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
[AssetManager] Loading dependency: sprites/sprites4.png, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
[DEBUG] Loading: 33%
[AssetManager] Loaded: 72.27248ms sprites/sprites4.png, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
[DEBUG] Loading: 44%
[AssetManager] Loaded: 116.72272ms sprites/sprites3.png, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
[DEBUG] Loading: 56%
[AssetManager] Loaded: 165.29959ms sprites/sprites2.png, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
[DEBUG] Loading: 67%
[AssetManager] Loaded: 237.17233ms sprites/sprites.png, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
[DEBUG] Loading: 78%
[AssetManager] Loaded: 341.5768ms sprites/sprites.atlas, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas
[DEBUG] Loading: 89%
[AssetManager] Loaded: 405.7238ms sprites/sprites.atlas, foo.bar.OutlineAtlas
```

Searching in the sources, I can't understand whether this is intentional or am I blindly doing something stupid ? (I also did not succed finding something about the topic in the wiki).

*EDIT:* Debug-print statements looks this way:

```
if (!assetManager.update()) {
    val progress = "${assetManager.progress * 100f}%"
    Gdx.app.debug("[DEBUG]", progress)
} else { ... }
```

Which is just `AssetManager.getProgress()` in Java.

Comment: Show how you calculate the percentage

Comment: @icarumbas I edited the question. I don't actually calculate anything, hence the question about _AssetManager_ itself.